# Angular translate - format dates

Tags: angularjs, localization, date-formatting, angular-translate

I am using Angular translate for my app localization. I'd like to dynamically change the date format depending on the user's locale.

- If the locale is French : format is `dd/mm/yyyy`
- If the locale is English/US : format is `mm/dd/yyyy`
- ...and so on depending on the locale's default date format

How can I achieve this (cleanly) with Angular translate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).
Dates can be formatted to locale default with this:

```
<td>{{user.lastLogin | amDateFormat:'l LT'}}</td>
```

To change the moment locale, use the following:

```
amMoment.changeLocale(language);
```

Don't forget to import the moment locale files for the languages you wish to support:

```
<script src="assets/global/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/de.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/es.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/fr.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/it.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/pl.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/ru.js"></script>
<script src="jslib/moment/zh-cn.js"></script>
```

And add angular moment module in your app:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am out of date, but I don't think angular-translate has anything to do with localization. So here are my solution (yet it very clean)

### If you are loading it only once per page reload use [angular-i18n](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n) will be enough. Install and put js file into your HTML

`bower install angular-i18n`

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_YOUR-LOCALE.js"></script>
```

### If you want to load it dynamically [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) :

`bower install angular-dynamic-locale`

```
<script src="myPath/tmhDynamicLocale.js"></script>
```

your js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['tmh.dynamicLocale', ...])

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', [..., 'tmhDynamicLocale',
    function… {
        tmhDynamicLocale.set('en');
    }
])
```

*NOTE, made sure you check the repo's readme for usage of `localeLocationPattern(string)`*

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is a very easy way to do it..
Not sure if it's clean but can be made clean.

you can use `interpolation` provided by angular-translate, the problem is you can't use `function` inside interpolation string, but you can do something cool.. 
pass a function inside the object you're interpolating and call that function while interpolation

say you need to put in `date`

```
{{ 'date' | translate:{date:"28/01/2016"} }}
//instead of this
{{ 'date' | translate:'{date:"28/01/2016",func: func}' }}//func comes from scope.
```

and in your `$translateProvider.translations`

```
$translateProvider.translations('en',{
   'date': "{{func(date)}}"
});
```

here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HQ1i513q6PDYj3b7nerg?p=preview)